# libclang: error: clang-c/Index.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, llvm-clang

i was trying to use clang to parse c++ code, but am unable to compile my source code because i am unable to find libclang headers.

I am running ubuntu 10.04 and have installed clang and llvm successfully from the repositories.

Please tell me where to find the file to include .

The example i am trying to run is :

```
    #include<clang-c/Index.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    CXIndex Index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
    CXTranslationUnit TU = clang_parseTranslationUnit(Index, 0,argv, argc, 0, 0, CXTranslationUnit_None);
    for (unsigned I = 0, N = clang_getNumDiagnostics(TU); I != N; ++I) {
    CXDiagnostic Diag = clang_getDiagnostic(TU, I);
    CXString String = clang_formatDiagnostic(Diag,
    clang_defaultDiagnosticDisplayOptions());
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", clang_getCString(String));
    clang_disposeString(String);
    }
    clang_disposeTranslationUnit(TU);
    clang_disposeIndex(Index);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think ubuntu packages have necessary headers and libraries to use libclang. You probably need to build llvm+clang from sources.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Banthar. Will try that and post back asap.

Comment: Yes your advice worked. Thank you.

Comment: On fedora I assumed this would be part of `llvm-devel` but I was missing `clang-devel`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package clang-2.7 from ubuntu 10.04 http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/devel/clang doesnt include header file `clang-c/Index.h`, nor have a libclang.so:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/clang/filelist

Neither do llvm-dev package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/llvm-dev/filelist

So, ubuntu 10.04 have no clang package with libclang or anything related to clang development.

As  Banthar suggested, you should use clang from llvm site, either built from sources (it is easy in ubuntu) or packed as binary package.

Comment: On Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit Desktop, I installed `libclang-3.4-dev`. It provides `/usr/lib/llvm-3.4/include/clang-c/Index.h`.

Comment: @AdamMonsen, Thanks for additional information! In newer ubuntus the situation is better.

Answer (score 5):

As [Adam Monsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156060/) said in a comment to the accepted answer, starting from Ubuntu 13.10, the file is provided by the following package:

`libclang-3.4-dev`

Change version number according to your requirements. The file resides in

`/usr/lib/llvm-3.4/include/clang-c/Index.h`

Comment: I just ran into this on Ubuntu 20.04 while trying to build/install  [rtags](https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags).  `sudo apt install libclang-dev` was good enough to fix it.